# CSV vs JSON file limits on PySpark

Tags: python, json, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working on Processing PCA analytics on data read from .json and .csv files using PySpark. I'm getting an out of memory error when I'm working with a .csv file size of only 77Mo, while with data from .json it can handle more than 1.2Go. 
Any explanation?
ps: I'm working in Standalone mode.
Here is my code for json:

```
df = sqlContext.read.json("bigdata.json")
vecAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["sepal_width", "sepal_length", "petal_width", "petal_length"], outputCol="features")
pca = PCA(k=2, inputCol="features", outputCol="pcaFeatures")
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[vecAssembler, pca])
model = pipeline.fit(df)
result = model.transform(df).select("pcaFeatures")
result.show(truncate=False)
```

and this is my code for csv:

```
fileObj = sc.textFile('iris.csv')
data = fileObj.map(lambda line: [float(k) for k in line.split(';')]).collect()
columns = (fileObj.first()).split(';')
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
vecAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=columns, outputCol="features")
pca = PCA(k=2, inputCol="features", outputCol="pcaFeatures")
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[vecAssembler, pca])
model = pipeline.fit(df)
result = model.transform(df).select("pcaFeatures")
result.show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewrite your code. For more understanding, Spark works on lazy evaluation. It have few functions which collect or actually process data, which are `collect`, `first`, `head`, `show`.

So here you are collecting data at first step. So there is no need to write `collect` function at start. Apart from this everything is fine.

`Collection` basically gathers data from all executors and load on driver. 
So after this `fileObj.map(lambda line: [float(k) for k in line.split(';')]).collect()` line your all task was performed on single driver/executor.

```
fileObj = sc.textFile('iris.csv')
data = fileObj.map(lambda line: [float(k) for k in line.split(';')])
columns = (fileObj.first()).split(';')
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
vecAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=columns, outputCol="features")
pca = PCA(k=2, inputCol="features", outputCol="pcaFeatures")
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[vecAssembler, pca])
model = pipeline.fit(df)
result = model.transform(df).select("pcaFeatures")
result.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: this works, but what if I add .cache()? what would it change ?

Comment: cache() is also a good option but we need  it when our data set is required more then once/frequently

Answer (score 1):

The reason is about your line:

```
data = fileObj.map(lambda line: [float(k) for k in line.split(';')]).collect()
```

The best process to that is doing like this:

```
data = fileObj.map(lambda line: [float(k) for k in line.split(';')])
columns = (fileObj.first()).split(';')
df = data.toDF(columns)
```

With `collect()` you are sending all your Data from your executors to your Driver. This should solve the problem